# Are questions related to the history and influences on the SF genre out of scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently asked a question regarding a specific time frame of the SF/horror genre, and I'm wondering if it is considered on-topic for this forum. The question touches on literary and political history, as well as philosophy, but all of it centered on impact to the SF genre in the 1920s/30s. The question itself arose from commentary on a specific 1927 SF/horror novel.

The question in question is:

[What was the 1920's/1930's SF/horror “literary ghetto”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/196411/105798)

Is the above question on topic? If not, is there a way to make it on-topic, or should it be removed?

It seems to me that Literature SE would be overly broad in scope for this question.

Comment: Is there anything that makes you *think* the question could be out of scope? It seems quite well-received.

Comment: @TARS I'm new here, and as I was scanning through the recent questions, it seems that nearly all of them are focused on story line and/or identification. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't going off-track by asking about the genre itself.

Comment: I was tempted to close it as being "too broad" but you've scoped it well and someone with the time, effort and energy could probably answer it without having to write a whole essay. It's probably not a great fit for the site (since it verges more into Literature) but it's definitely on-topic, imho.

Comment: @Valorum - it's a perfect fit for the site. Just because you don't personally like it doesn't make it "not a fit".

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - I didn't say it's not a fit. I said that it's not a *great* fit. I'm sure OP will get an answer, but whether it's the best answer they can find on the network is a very different matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Questions of this type are rare but on-topic here.**

We have a [terminology](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tag and a [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) tag, both of which have a good history of being used for questions which didn't end up closed as off-topic, and both of which seem very pertinent to your question. I haven't seen very *many* questions like yours here, but it seems to fall within the site's scope, and an expert on the sci-fi genre would be the best person to answer it.

Bear in mind, though, that although questions of this type are OK, *most* of the (non-story-ID) questions here are about specific works of sci-fi or fantasy. This has meant that our community of 'experts' has gravitated more towards experts in specific SF/F universes rather than experts in the history of the genre. We have a lot of Harry Potter experts, Star Trek experts, Doctor Who experts, and so on, but fewer history-of-scifi experts. We do have a few of the latter, though, and hopefully someone will be able to answer your question.

---

<sub>Since you mention Literature SE, I'll add that this would *also* be on-topic there. Note that Literature is a much smaller and less active site than SFF, so you'd probably get less eyeballs on your question there ... but on the other hand, [terminology](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) / [history-of-literature](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-literature) questions like this one are (proportionally) more common there. It's your choice where to post, since it's on-topic on two different sites, but do pick just one of them rather than cross-posting on both sites.</sub>

Comment: You allude to it here _"It's your choice where to post, since it's on-topic on two different sites."_ but probably worth explicitly stating that cross posting the question on two different sites on the network at the same time isn't allowed (or at least highly discouraged, I can't remember the exact ruling on it now).

Comment: @The Good point; edited to mention that.

Comment: Here is the related meta regarding cross posting questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu